# Gradlew errors while executing while inspecting on lint in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, lint

I'm using lint to debug my code and I'm getting an error at this part of code

```
for fi arg in "$@"; do
    CHECK=`echo "$arg"|egrep -c "$OURCYGPATTERN" -`
    CHECK2=`echo "$arg"|egrep -c "^-"`
```

the pointer shows error at " $@ ;" after ; and says expected a command.
Any solution to debug this ?
Please help

Comment: delete the fi after the for